# How random32_unbiased function works in Monero's Schnorr signiture algorithm

Tags: c++, cryptography, monero

In the [Zero to Monero book](https://www.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf), I am reading about [Schnorr signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature). Section 2.3.4 references the `random32_unbiased()` function from [`src/crypto/crypto.cpp`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/de3456e1275836725291ba71036b7ef0e2cda91f/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L123) of the [codebase](https://github.com/monero-project/monero). My understsanding is that this function generates a random integer between `1` and `l-1` (both inclusive), where `l` is a large integer.

That function is:

```
void random32_unbiased(unsigned char *bytes)
  {
    // l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493.
    // l fits 15 times in 32 bytes (iow, 15 l is the highest multiple of l that fits in 32 bytes)
    static const unsigned char limit[32] = { 0xe3, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x72, 0x8b, 0xce, 0x13, 0x29, 0x8f, 0x30, 0x82, 0x8c, 0x0b, 0xa4, 0x10, 0x39, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0 };
    while(1)
    {
      generate_random_bytes_thread_safe(32, bytes);
      if (!less32(bytes, limit))
        continue;
      sc_reduce32(bytes);
      if (sc_isnonzero(bytes))
        break;
    }
  }
```

What purpose does the line with `static const unsigned char limit[32]` have?

My main question is the above one, but in general, I do not deeply understand how function works, so an explanation would be appreciated too.

Comment: I'm guessing based on the comment that it's 15*l. This method implements a subtlety about picking random integers between two limits using a source of random bits (or bytes). If you just took 32 random bytes and reduced it mod l it would introduce a slight bias. If you took 32 random bytes and threw out any value >= l it would eliminate the bias but it would throw away most values and would take too long. By throwing away everything >= 15*l and then reducing the result mod l you eliminate the bias and, on average, take less than 2 trips through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monero uses `edwards25519` as the underlying elliptic curve which it uses to produce `EdDSA` (Edwards digital signatures), to create transactions on the Monero blockchain.

`edwards25519` is a curve which is of composite order, that is, it's not a prime order curve like `secp256k1`, which is used by Bitcoin.

Owing to this fact, in cryptographic contexts we must work in a prime order *subgroup* of the curve, so our group is prime, for security reasons.

That subgroup for Monero is ~8-times smaller than the order of the actual curve! Thus the subgroup size is `l`, i.e. `2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493`

So, there can only be `2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493` valid public keys for Monero, or anything else using `edwards25519`

As James K. Polk points out, we want to ensure we stay inside the cyclic subgroup, but not introduce bias in the key material.

Interestingly, I stuck `l` into sagemath, multiplied it by 15, and indeed it does fit in 256-bits.

`255.906890595609` to be exact, 16 times would require `256.000000000000000000000000000000000000005` bits. Math yo.